# Web element for image

Tags: image, onclick, tags

How to find the web element for the following code: 
`<a onclick="deleteFilterByID('incident','r516193c05161f1d051619e505161e190');" tabindex="0">
<img id="img_r516193c05161f1d051619e505161e190" class="filerTableAction" border="0" title="Delete" alt="Delete" src="images/closex_hover.gifx"/>`

Kindly help

Comment: Sorry can you explain or rephrase your question a bit further?

Comment: Hi Tariq. I got the answer of my question. I was looking at it in wrong way. Posted answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Answer of my question like this:

By.cssSelector("a[onclick*='incident'] > img[src*='closex_hover.gifx']")